# Apache Jakarta (Tomcat) Connector to forward traffic to specific Tomcat

Tags: apache, iis, tomcat, load-balancing, connector

There is one use case I am unable to solve so far with the Apache Jakarta (Tomcat) Connector load balancing feature.

I have one IIS site which has one Apache Tomcat Connector attached to it.  I need to "forward" the traffic to a different Tomcat depending on the URI that is requested.  It is pretty simple to do when you only have apps with a specific context (like /app1, /app2, etc).  My problem is that I have one app (in one Tomcat) that is at / (ROOT) and one other app (in another Tomcat) that is at /app1.

I have tried the following config in uriworkermap.properties:

```
/*=loadBalancer1
/app1/*=loadBalancer2
```

But this doesn't work, because "loadBalancer1" takes all the traffic.  "loadBalancer2" is being ignored, which make sense, since /app1/* matches /* (regexp wise).

I also tried adding a exclusion as so:

```
/*=loadBalancer1
!/app1/*=loadBalancer1
/app1/*=loadBalancer2
```

But that doesn't work either, because "loadBalancer1" is still taking all the traffic, but just ignoring that "/app1/*" URI pattern.  "loadBalancer2" is simply ignored again.

Any suggestion, keeping in mind that I cannot have 2 IIS sites, nor can I move the app that is at / (ROOT) to a different context path in Tomcat?

Thank you

**Edit:**
Instead of using just one Apache Tomcat Connector, I use 1 connector for each Tomcat on the same IIS site.

uriworkermap.properties #1: for Tomcat with app at / (ROOT)

```
/*=wlb
!/app1/*=wlb
```

uriworkermap.proerties #2: for Tomcat with app at /app1

```
/app1/*=wlb
```

Connector #1 will ignore traffic on URI "/app1/*", but connector #2 will catch it (and vice versa).

Now I can set different VM options and memory allocation to my apps!

I am open to comments or better solution..

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you reverse it as such ?

```
/app1/*=loadBalancer2
/*=loadBalancer1
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.  I tried it.  Seems that the regexp (if this is what they use) has priority over the ordering of elements in the config file. That said, a coworker probably found the solution. I will post it as soon as I can.